# Change Accordion arrow position

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery Mobile. I created an Accordion, But I want the arrow on it to appear on Right side.
Can anyone help me?

Below is my code.

```
<div class="accordion" id = "accordion">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #333333;
    .accordion h3 a {
        width:50%
    }
    .accordion h3 a .ui-icon {
        float:right
    }
}
```

Then i loaded my Accordion with arrays

```
for (i=0;i<names.length;i++)
  {               
      var newDiv = "<h3>"+names[i]+"</h3><p>"+subnames[i]+"</p>";
       $('.accordion').append(newDiv)
       $('.accordion').accordion("refresh");

}
```

Comment: Post your CSS and some more HTML

Comment: <style>
                        body
                        {
                            background-color: #333333;
                            .accordion h3 a {width:50%}
                            .accordion h3 a .ui-icon {float:right}
                        }
                    
                    
                    
                  
                        
                        </style>

Comment: This isn't related to jQM. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jQuery Mobile collapsible widget, you can set `data-iconpos="right"` to move the icon to the right side:

```
    <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right">
             <h3>Section 1</h3>

            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right">
             <h3>Section 2</h3>

            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right">
             <h3>Section 3</h3>

            <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qroheh37/)**

For dynamically added content:

```
   var thedynamiccontent = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right"><h3>Another Section</h3><p>Hello from dynamic added section</p></div><div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right"><h3>Another Section 2</h3><p>Hello from dynamic added section 2</p></div>'; 
   $("#accordion").append(thedynamiccontent).collapsibleset("refresh").enhanceWithin();
```

> dynamic **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qroheh37/1/)**

NOTE: you can also change the icons used: `data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u"`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like what you got should work:

```
.accordion h3 a .ui-icon {
    float:right
}
```

Please make sure you are executing or loading your custom CSS **after** the jQM-CSS. You could also try the !important statement:

```
.accordion h3 a .ui-icon {
    float:right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-icons-alignment

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -8px; 
}
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { 
    padding-left: 1em; 
}
```